# How to route incoming and outgoing traffic through vpn host with iptables

Tags: debian, iptables, openvpn, port-forwarding

I am trying to route traffic coming into a network through a raspberry pi and to/from my personal computer which is running a game server and is on a different network. The raspberry pi is hosting OpenVPN and my computer is able to connect to it, and is given the static ip 10.8.0.2. I have tried using

`iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 7777 -j DNAT --to-destination 10.8.0.2:7777`

`iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE`

but I get a connection timeout error when trying to connect to the server. I have also run the first command with port 27015, which is the query port for the server. I am very new to this so I may not know exactly what I am doing.

Answer (score 0):

For such a redirection you need

- the DNAT rule (which you have)
- a rule which allows forwarding (in the `FORWARD` chain)
- routing must be enabled (`sysctl`, `net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1`)

Use `tcpdump` for checking whether the redirected packets leave the system.

Comment: Do you know what a forwarding rule would look like? I'm not sure exactly what would work best in my situation

Comment: @BobSinker In this case that could be `iptables -A FORWARD -d 10.8.0.2 -p udp --dport 7777 -j ACCEPT`